# Closedness of $\{(x, x) :x\neq 0\}$ in dictionary order topology

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $F:\mathbb R\times \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be defined by the equation

$$F(x,y)=\begin{cases} \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2} & \text{if }(x,y)\neq (0,0)\\ 
0 & \text{if } (x, y) = (0,0).\end{cases}$$

Show that $F$ is not continuous.

I got a solution. But I am not convinced.

It says "$F(x,y)=1/2$ implies $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ and $(x−y)^2=0$ . Therefore, $$F^{−1}(\{1/2\})=\{(x,x)|x\neq 0\}$$
is not closed."

I can not understand how $F^{−1}(\{1/2\})=\{(x,x)|x\neq 0\}$ is not closed. Of course this is not closed in $\mathbb R^2$ in standard topology. But in       ' Dictionary Order Topology' It is closed.

Comment: But why do you care about dictionary order topology?

Comment: Without Caring topology how one check Closedness?@JohnMa

Comment: Why don't you just use standard topology?

Comment: If it was in standard topology then $R^2$ would have been in the place  $R\times \mathbb R$

Comment: So you are saying that since it is written as $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$, so it is not using standard product topology? Why?

Comment: Yes.......................@JohnMa

Comment: $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ has the product topology (or equivalently the Euclidean metric topology) **unless** it is explicitly stated otherwise. And then $x_n = (\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}) \to (0,0)$ while $F(x_n) \equiv 1 \to 1 \neq F(0,0)$ so $F$ is not continuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set $\{(x,x):x\neq 0\}$ is indeed closed in the dictionary order topology, and not closed in the standard topology.  Obviously, this problem is talking about the standard topology, not the dictionary order topology.  (It's called "standard" for a reason--it's the default topology that is assumed unless stated otherwise.)

Comment: But why they did not use $R\times \mathbb R$ ?@Eric Wofsey

Comment: @cmi they= who? Munkres? if so, what exercise?

Comment: Yes Mukresh. Exercise 18 problem no 12